# The following versions are almost identical, so why does only one work?

Tags: reactjs

Please excuse the crudeness. But, why does the following work ...

```
{
  !submitted && !success && <button className="form-field" type="submit" title="Submit registration form">Register</button>
}
{
  submitted && success && <div className="success-message">Success! Thank you for registering</div>
}
```

and the following doesn't. The code is almost identical and the only difference is the two braces in the middle. So, why?

```
{
  !submitted && !success && <button className="form-field" type="submit" title="Submit registration form">Register</button>

  submitted && success && <div className="success-message">Success! Thank you for registering</div>
}
```

**Please Note**

For the interested, one way to improve the code would be to use the ternary operator. However, to understand why the above doesn't work, have a look at the answers below.

```
{
  submitted && success ? 
    <div className="success-message">Success! Thank you for registering.</div> :
    <button className="form-field" type="submit" title="Submit registration form">Register</button>
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to run Javascript inside the render method of react, you need to tell the compiler where it by using the `{}` inside the JSX elements.

Using a conditional render is the equivalent of writing this:

```
if (!submitted && !success) {
  return (
    <div>text</div>
  )
}
```

So, the second example cannot be compiled because it would be something like this:

```
if (!submitted && !success) {
  return (
    <div>text</div>
  )submitted && success && <div className="success-message">Success! Thank you for registering</div>
}
```

which is obviously wrong.

When JSX is rendered inside a conditional rendering code, it is wrapped with parenthesis and the code block that runs the Javascript is exited.

The second example you showed doesn't work (and that's right) because after the first conditional render, it expects to read JSX.

See how conditional rendering works [here](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html#inline-if-with-logical--operator)

and

[See more here](https://reactjs.org/docs/introducing-jsx.html#embedding-expressions-in-jsx)

Comment: Thank you for your answer... Although, the specified link doesn't exactly address my problem (unless I missed it). If I understand this correctly, I think you were trying to say that it is only possible to put a single expression inside of the curly braces? So, since I have two expressions, I need two pairs of curly braces?

Comment: Correct @Grateful, every expression needs to be wrapped in curly braces. If you want to remove the middle braces one other way to do it is concatenate the expressions with `&&` but I wouldn't suggest that!

Comment: Wow! That new "first" link was just what I needed! Obviously, the way around the problem above would be to reduce both expressions into one... Using the ternary operator.

Comment: Yeap, that's an other option :)